# how to open apple map on Iphone5 phone gap

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, cordova

I already have developed a mobile app in phone gap and it is working fine in android and Iphone 4 because I am using google map to load the store's information. But in Iphone5, I can't open google maps and I dont know how to open Apple map instead.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What Have You Tried? http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.com/2012/12/prove-that-you-have-tried.html

Comment: We can't guess what you have done. Code would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ace,
Please see my code to show the address in google map.. Is there any way I can make it to show in Apple map instead for IPhone 5? I am using a below code to show the google map on button click
$('.map-details').live('click',function() {var mapTitle = $(this).siblings('h2').html();map_initialize(mapTitle,$(this).data('lat'),$(this).data('lon'));$("#map-link").attr('href','http://maps.google.ca/maps?hl=en&q=' + encodeURI(mapTitle) + '@' + $(this).data('lat') + ',' + $(this).data('lon') + "&zoom=16");});

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: Thanks very much.. I am a bit new in it. Can you help me to give a sample code.. So so i need to use only this library or keep using google maps which I am already doing and check if the IOS version is 6 then use apple map?? any code would be really help full.. thanks again

Comment: I may supply code later, unfortunately I am very busy today. Anyway, if you use MKMapView, it will use whatever the default maps application is. So on iOS 5 and lower, it will use Google Maps, on iOS 6+ it will use Apple Maps. You really don't have to do anything separate.

Comment: It seems like C language sdk frame work .. My application is based in php and jquery. How would use it in my code?

Comment: ... Oh. That changes things. I didn't know what phonegap was until just now. I assumed you were using the Cocoa environment. (You didn't do anything wrong, but most people around here just use the tag ios for cocoa, but they shouldn't) Anyway, I am not sure what to tell you now. I don't do CSS, Javascript, and HTML very much. Only for what I do with Firefox. All I can say is good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To open Apple Maps, the easiest way is using a HTML style link:

**Open Maps:**

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/">Open Apple Maps</a>
```

**Open Maps with route:**

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=">Open Route in Apple Maps</a>
```

Where saddr is the start address and daddr is the destination address. You can pass "Current%20Location" to use their current location